# Figuring out the direct stream url of an internet station

Tags: internet, streaming, url, sniffing, radio

I enjoy listening to a station called Gone Up radio, but for some reason I can't access it with my Imperial i150 internet radio. It seems to be an aac stream, according to the sniffers I've tried (like Bulk Media Downloader), and that's officially supported by my internet radio.

This is the pop up player where the information is stored:
https://www.goneup.fr/pop-up-player

These are two urls working correctly in Winamp, but not in my internet radio:
https://stream.goneupradio.com/radio
https://stream.goneupradio.com/radiomp3

I guess these are 'shortened' urls instead of the direct/raw ones. Is there somebody who can figure out the direct/raw ones? I've tried everything possible (within my capacities, like sniffers - but Wireshark seemed a bridge too far).

There also seemed to be related url containing manager-radio.goneupradio.com/8000, but that didn't bring me any further. A manager.goneupradio.com url has also been found.

Comment: You can simply enable the developer tools in your web browser and switch to the network tab. There you will find the called urls, for example https://stream.goneupradio.com/radio?ver=837956

Comment: That ?ver=...... part is always different. That's the strange thing about it. I knew about that network tab already.